# How to correctly specify the type of the argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `ButtonTypes` class:

```
class ButtonTypes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.textType = "text"
        self.callbackType = "callback"
        self.locationType = "location"
        self.someAnotherType = "someAnotherType"
```

And a function that should take one of the attributes of the `ButtonTypes` class as an argument:

```
def create_button(button_type):
    pass
```

How can I specify that the argument of the `create_button` function should not just be a string, but exactly one of the attributes of the `ButtonTypes` class?

Something like this:
`def create_button(button_type: ButtonTypes.Type)`

As far as I understand, I need to create a `Type` class inside the `ButtonTypes` class, and then many other classes for each type that inherit the `Type` class, but I think something in my train of thought is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want an `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class ButtonTypes(Enum):
    textType = "text"
    callbackType = "callback"
    locationType = "location"
    someAnotherType = "someAnotherType"

def func(button_type: ButtonTypes):
    # Use button_type
```

The `enum` specifies a closed set of options that the variable must be a part of.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. I read about the `enum` class and I still have a question: I can still send just `ButtonTypes` as an argument instead of `ButtonTypes.textType` and this will cause an error. Is there any way to specify that it's not just `ButtonTypes`, but `ButonTypes.someType`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an enumerated type.

```
from enum import Enum

class ButtonType:
    TEXT = "text"
    CALLBACK = "callback"
    LOCATION = "location"
    SOMETHINGELSE = "someOtherType"


def create_button(button_type: ButtonType):
    ...
```

This goes one step further: not only are there only 4 values of type `ButtonType`, but *no* string will work, even at runtime, since your function will either ignore the string value associated with the `ButtonType` value altogether, or use code to extract the string that will break if `button_type` is an arbitrary string.